# How to pass email values from one php page to another

Tags: redirect, forms

Good evening,
I have two subscription forms (mailclimp) i want to pass the email value from one php page to another. In the code below i add the
`/** session_start(); **/` in comments because show me some errors.

The first page :

```
    <?php
    /** session_start(); **/
    ob_start();
    $_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;
    ?>

  <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" 
    name="varname" value="var_value" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
```

The second page:

```
<?php
/** session_start(); **/
ob_start();
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
?>

  <input type="email" name="varname" value="<?php echo $var_value?>" 
    class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
```

But not passed the email value from the first page to another. Also i try to add as parameter the cookies, but the problem not solved.

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

---

**Updates**
I add this wireframe to help the users the process that i want to fix.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*first.php:*

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['wdm_email'] = 'info@wisdmlabs.com';
?>
```

-

*second.php:*

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Hi ' . $_SESSION['wdm_email'];
?>
```

-

When you will run second.php(after first.php), output would be:

```
Hi info@wisdmlabs.com
```

-

***Do not forget to start the session at the top of the pages.***

For more references: [How to use session?](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: thanks for the response. I dont want to "echo" the email field from another page to another, but i want to pass the email value. I edit my question and i include the wireframe to help the users better.

Comment: Also i realized that if i remove my comments of  `session_start()` then i receive some errors like : `session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:127)` , how can fix that?

Comment: Please start the session at the top of the page.

Comment: @WishmLabs, i add the `_SESSION();` at the top of the page. General i don't want to pass the name but the value of the email field.

Comment: Please session in not working in my computer. How can I fix it. But same program is working in another computer.